# Как отправлять email на python

Tags: python, smtp, email

Не могу разобраться с smtp в python.
Примеры не особо помогают.
Пытаюсь через отправлять письма через свой smtp сервер

Comment: Простейший работающий пример для версии 3 будет очень полезен

Comment: Посмотрите самый=самый первый вопрос на Хэшкоде.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дмитрий все гуд написал, но если через свой смтп-сервер, то в строке

```
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
```

переменную smtp_server указывать просто не надо. таким образом строка преобретает вид -

```
s = smtplib.SMTP()
```

затем добавляешь строку

```
s.connect()
```

и все! готово! можешь проверять.

Answer (score 4):

Вот пример отправки письма

```
import smtplib   
from email.mime.text import MIMEText    
me = 'admin@mail.ru'
you = 'kot_smit@mail.ru'
smtp_server = 'smtp.mail.ru'
msg = MIMEText('Message e-mail')
msg['Subject'] = 'The contents of '
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
s = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server)
s.sendmail(me, [you], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```